# "A stop job is running..." on shutdown

Tags: debian, systemd, gnome3, shutdown, reboot

Almost every time when I'm shutting down or rebooting the system I get the following message before the system actually shuts down:

```
A stop job is running for Session 1 of user xy
```

It waits for 1:30min and then continues with the shutdown.
I'm using Debian stretch with Gnome 3. This message does not appear in the syslog.

Any ideas?

Comment: The other question is more recent, but has more answers. It has the same answer below (literally copy-pasted) and another answer with more votes.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, searching I found a post in a reddit forum of Arch Linux.

Here is the solution that works for me
https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/4bawf7/a_stop_job_is_running_for_session_c2_of_user/d17th3u

> Install watchdog
>
> `# pacman -S watchdog`
>
> And then start the service at boot:
>
> `#  systemctl enable watchdog.service`
>
> Start the service to don't see the message any more
>
> `# systemctl start watchdog.service`

I create a gist for this https://gist.github.com/dianjuar/98d02af4050dc2df8ae6f18695d44ca3

Comment: This solution doesn't work for debian 9.2. I just tried it.